# Request for references when other sources have failed

Tags: support

This is an entirely personal problem, but am not convinced it is unique. I have been trying to find information on London's Foundling Hospital (Coram's Hospital) and can discover very little either online or printed. The information may not exist, but, given preliminary research, would it be off-topic to pose the question?

Comment: I believe there's an existing meta consensus that this would be on topic, especially if you specify you're looking for primary sources. My understanding is that source requests are only off topic when it's in the form of "recommend books to read on x".

Comment: @Semaphore Thanks. I half remembered this was the case, but wanted to confirm.

Comment: @TheHonRose I'm not sure about what's online or printed, but there's a lot of info available in the archives. AFAIR most is held at the [London Metropolitan Archives](https://www.cityoflondon.gov.uk/things-to-do/london-metropolitan-archives/Pages/default.aspx) (their catalogue is searchable online), but there is other material at the East Sussex Record Office. :)

Comment: @sempaiscuba Many thanks for that! I've scoured the National Archives site, with zero success so far! I'll try the London Metropolitan one, again, many thanks.